# Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restart

Tags: mysql

```
Notification Exception: (Env:Production) : : java.lang.String :
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [ UPDATE txn_tracker set status=?,
schedule_dt=SYSDATE() where txn_id =? and status=? ]; 
Deadlock found when trying   to get lock; try restart
```

How to cope with this Exception

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch it and retry the transaction. Some tips to reduce the chance of deadlocks in mysql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html